# Concurrent Map of Queues

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to implement a map of queues which is appended to by multiple threads after each worker has finished processing.

Once all of the threads have finished execution, I want to write to a file using the information from the queues.

So far I have attempted to create a Concurrent Map:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Queue<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

and a hash map of Concurrent Linked queues:

```
Map<String, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Adding to the map:

```
for(File f : dir.listFiles(){
  map.put(f.getName(), new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>());
}
```

Code to add to the map in the Thread, I loop over all of the queues to check the key values for a condition:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Queue<String>> entry : queueListInThread.entrySet(){
  if(entry.getKey().equals(/*fileName from the thread */) entry.getValue().add(someString);
}
```

Code to get the queue values in the Manager, looping through all of the queues and extracting all of the values:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Queue<String>> entry : map.entrySet(){
  String line;
  while((line = entry.getValue().poll()) != null{
    //do stuff with the value
  }
}
```

Neither of these approaches seems to work, and despite confirming that the threads are correctly adding to the queues, when I loop through the map to find the entries in each queue, the size of the queue is 0.

Along side the code that I have, I have implemented a single `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` which is appended to correctly and works as it should - the problem is that I need to key value corresponding to each queue to determine the output file to write to.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: There's not enough information here. *How* did those approaches not work? What was the difference between what you expected and what happened? Give us a [mcve].

Comment: Edit: When I loop through the map to find the entries in each queue, the size of the queue is 0. I'll try to put together some code representing what I've tried.

Comment: The for loop for adding is somewhat strange (why do you go over all the queues?), but there isn't anything obviously wrong there.. post more code! :)

Comment: Just checking - you create the queues beforehand, right?

Comment: Literally just added the code for creating the queues. And I loop through the queues to check the key.

Comment: So what are the `/* conditions */`?

Comment: Are `queue` and `queueList` the same thing?  Also I agree with xs0 that the conditions, and the locking under which you test them, may be the issue here.

Comment: for(Map.Entry<String, Queue<String>> entry : queueListInThread.entrySet({
  if(entry.getKey().equals(/*fileName from the thread */) entry.getValue().add(someString);
} is massively inefficient. You should be using map.get(fileName).add(string).

Comment: Apologies, hopefully the names make more sense name. I've added the conditions. But the conditions definitely aren't the issue. I've verified that the thread is adding to the queues. I would have though lack of locking would lead to a change in order/some values not getting added. The issue here is that no values are returned to the manager

Comment: There is no point of using a map and then iterating over the keys to find the one you need. Just use `queueListInThread.get(/*fileName from the thread */).add(someString);`.

Comment: Hmm, do you wait for the threads to finish? Using `Thread.join()` or something else?

Comment: Are you doing the loop over and over? If not, your manager might loop through every entry before anything gets added.

Comment: I use an executor service, and call .shutdown() before reading from the queues.

Comment: !! Changing the loop to a .get().add() seems to have fixed the issue. I'm not sure why looping through the values doesn't work - I would have thought it would just be less efficient. Thanks everyone.